# Spotfire Date Ranks Incorrectly

Tags: spotfire

Really odd issue here- I've created a calculated column for a RowID purpose that is `DenseRank([STRT DT], "ASC", [Prprty]`. The goal of this calculated column is to rank the date as time goes on. This has worked perfectly for all instances I've checked up until now. The STRT DT column remains consistent but somehow, the count fails about midway through the dataset.

I've attached two images showing my data- first image is the correct ranking up to row 46 (highlighted where the off count starts in blue), and second image shows the rows that are being counted continuous in the ranking system, but aren't being ranked correctly. Has this happened to anyone and is there a solution/way around something like this?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

[image: Requested Row ID IMG]

Comment: the ranking is defined grouping with [Prprty]. Is that the column shown in the screenshots (the one valued 75257.00)? What is the datatype?

Comment: The data type for [Prprty] is a Real. Should I have that changed?

Comment: I was just thinking that the change in rank might be a consequence of a slight change in precision for [Prprty]. What happens if you create a property that rounds off [Prprty] to, say, two decimal figures and use that for the DenseRank group?

Comment: I just tried to round the [prprty] and that didn't solve the issue. I also tried to change the type of [prprty] to string and integer and that didn't work either. Would you think that there could be something coming from the [strt dt] column that would have an effect on this?

Comment: I reproduced it to some extent by setting the date to a string. Can you check that your date property [STRT DT] is stored with a datetime data type? In string comparison, 10 comes before 9.

Comment: I hate [STRT DT] stored as a string, but I just tried to do a new calculated column DateTime([STRT DT]) and used this in the dense rank and I'm still having an issue with the Row ID. Would you think that because I had it originally as a string that it should come in as a DateTime? Maybe it never truly overcomes the string format?

Comment: can you show an example of how this row id goes wrong?

Comment: I added a new picture in the post... the picture shows a red highlighted data section that is dated 3/10/2023, but the green highlighted data below should have a lower Row ID value because the [STRT DT] for these green fields are older than 3/10/2023. Row ID is a calculated column that is DenseRank( [STRT DT], "ASC", [Prprty]). [STRT DT] is in a string format, but I tried to change it to a DateTime format and I still have the same issue with the incorrect Row IDs. [Prprty] is a Real, but I've tried to change it to a string, integer, and a rounded real, but this hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are still using a string. If the data type of the [STR DT] column is not DateTime, you will get RowID ordered as a string, with 3/4/2023 coming before 3/10/2023, as you are experiencing. To work around this, I tried it with the earlier snippet of data you provided, leaving [STR DT] as a string, and defining the RowID column as

```
DenseRank(DateTime([STR DT]),"ASC",[Prprty])
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried again to change the [STRT DT] column to a DateTime format and this seemed to solve the issue! Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it!